# Does a non-overlapped Serial Port connection block a write during read (and vice versa)?

Tags: c++, serial-port

When opening a serial port connection using CreateFile (in C++ on a Windows platform), you can choose between opening it as overlapped or non-overlapped.

If opened as non-overlapped a ReadFile, or a WriteFile call is blocking, i.e., it doesn't return until ready.

My question is if these function calls block each other when executed in separate threads. If one thread does a ReadFile, will another thread be able to do a WriteFile before all reading is done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. From MSDN:

"If one thread is blocked waiting for its I/O operation to complete, all other threads that subsequently call a communications API will be blocked until the original operation completes. For instance, if one thread were waiting for a ReadFile function to return, any other thread that issued a WriteFile function would be blocked."

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx#serial_topic4)